# Pre-customize My Toolbar for users of a given role or domain?

Tags: content-editor, ribbon

I'm not finding anything on this, and when I try to play around with items in the `core` database, I'm not seeing them change for a given user.  Any idea if this is possible to do?  I'm adding them under `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/My Strip`.

I can edit the Customize item under that and it gets reflected when I log in as a different user, but adding sibling items to Customize don't seem to show up, and there is no security assigned to those items just as there are none for the Customize item...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values for this are stored in the registry per user. Below is an example on how to modify the data with Sitecore PowerShell Extensions (SPE).

```powershell
$ribbonCommands = "{D33A0641-9F1C-4984-8342-0655C3D0F123}|{EDA2F1DC-0412-45B2-9FDD-0700B03F28CB}|{93F6C3FE-B36E-4083-BA48-19DE43F19F49}"
$registryKey = "/Current_User/Ribbon/My Strip"

<#
  Current_User is automatically replaced by the Sitecore API
  Optionally replace Current_User with domain\username if you want 
  to apply to a different user than the one logged in
#>
[Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Registry]::SetValue($registryKey, $ribbonCommands)
```

[image]

#### Update

One option to consider is to have a process run either periodically or during login that would ensure the user has the appropriate settings applied. SPE has an integration point for this.

Comment: Sorry, what is SPE, and where are you specifying this code?  Thanks.

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation site. https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/

Comment: So it looks like this can't assign this to a role, only to individual users?

Comment: That appears to be the case.

Comment: Is it then possible to create a powershell script that does this when a new user is create in the system and that user belongs to a specific domain?

Comment: You can do all that and Mike Reynolds laundry.